# New navigation page does not remember settings when clicking the NEW tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

The values of *show* and *sort* are stored if I reload the page or click on *Questions*. But if I click on the *new* tab the default values are always shown, which are *recommended* and *recently active*.

And 0 questions?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.