# The view settings aren't remembered

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

For example, I really like viewing the questions by need answer, all tags, sorted by newest. However, when I go to and from other pages, I need to reselect these. For example, I may click on the logo to return to the questions list. When I do, it changes the view to new, recommended, sorted by recently active.

Related issues:

[New navigation page does not remember settings when clicking the NEW tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256882/new-navigation-page-does-not-remember-settings-when-clicking-the-new-tab)

This question does discuss the view, but it appears that it's saying that show and sort are stored. I'm not actually seeing the behavior. For example:

I click on "need answer", I set the filter to "all tags", the show to "no answer" and the sort to "votes". Based on this question, I expect to be able to click on "Questions" and then on "need answer" and have my settings preserved. I don't see that - I see the filter set to "all tags", the show to "need answer", and the sort to "newest".

My bug (or maybe a feature-request, not sure yet) is that the "Questions" tab as well as the filtering, showing, and votes should be consistent every time I hit the homepage. For example, hitting the homepage should remember if I'm viewing by new, popular, or need answers. It should also remember my filter, show, and sort settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New navigation page does not remember settings when clicking the NEW tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256882/new-navigation-page-does-not-remember-settings-when-clicking-the-new-tab)

Comment: @juergend Unless I don't understand that question, I don't think so. Editing now.

Comment: Since there are now 2 duplicate votes, can someone explain how my issue is related to the other one? I've read it a few times now and I see two different issues...

Comment: I agree it's not a duplicate question, it's probably getting the votes because the same solution would fix both problems. The other question is probably a subset of this broader one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been completed and is out in new nav alpha 2.