# Clicking Meta Logo/"Questions" in New Nav doesn't work as expected

Tags: discussion, design, new-nav

One of my favorite things is being able to click the site logo to go back to the most recent activity page. Apparently, part of the New Nav changes was to make the logo sticky... I don't like this (and I'm guessing I'm not the only one).

Now, it doesn't work and I have no clue how to get back to that page and I **really** don't like it (not sure I mentioned that)...

I'm now permanently stuck on the "Bounties" page. See the URL in the image below and the content of the page:

[image: Do NOT LIKE]

Please reconsider this change.

Also, the "Questions" button doesn't do what it's supposed to do, either. The usual result of hitting the "Questions" button usually takes you to the most recently asked questions. Now it just does the same thing as the logo... which is pointless... why have two buttons that do the same exact thing?

If you really want to do this, make the Questions button "sticky" and put the Meta button back to what it was.

Comment: Opt out of the alpha test. Hope it won't go through. Join the club. :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, that is surprisingly [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

It says specifically in the question where a mod announced the new navigation system:

[image]

When you clicked on the `x Bounties` button (x is a whole number), your most recent tab becomes `need answers`. So when you click on the the Meta logo, it just stays there because your most recent tab is `need answers`. This is supposed to work when you click on a question and you want to return to your rightful tab.

EDIT: Since this is now a feature-request, I will put my second part of this answer here.

This seems to be a predicament as the tab you clicked on becomes the most recent tab you use. Of course, you could do it the old-fashioned way by clicking the back arrow or just checking your history.

What should happen that the system remembers the last ***two*** tabs/activity pages. If you press the logo while you are **not** in a page shows you the question and answers, you go back to the second most recent activity page. Otherwise, you go back to the most recent activity page.

Comment: DO NOT LIKE. Should I change to a feature request... or discussion? This also doesn't mention why the behavior is identical with the "Questions" button.

Comment: Yes, change it to a feature-request.

Comment: But the URL of the page is **just** meta.stackexchange.com. If I go to that URL I should **Always** get the Recent activity page. With this change, I can't just get to the default page any more.

Answer (score 4):

I miss having the functionality of going to different pages based on whether I hit the "Questions" link or whether I hit the main logo. I used them at different times for different reasons. I hope that the differentiation will be restored.

Comment: Then be sure to also check [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259278/162011). This bug fix needs your votes!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: we have a few ideas on how to make this work better in the next iteration

---

We had [exactly the opposite feedback the last iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256929/the-view-settings-arent-remembered/259267#259267). It would be much preferable there was a neutral discussion question about it so we could evaluate both points of view as once.

Ultimately, what matters is what *problem* we are solving with our choices rather than personal preferences. At the moment, it's not clear what this change prevents and what going back would enable: if you need to go back to the "new" tab, just click new.

Please consider opening a neutrally worded question to discuss this so both sides can participate.

Comment: But that question is specifically talking about the "Questions" button... not the Site Logo!... so it was implemented incorrectly. Using the "Questions" button this way keeps with the current implementation of the site. Regardless, I'm in the middle of writing a discussion thread.

Comment: It would be useful if you accepted my suggestion: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that... you do realize that clicking on the logo and the "Questions" buttons now have the same exact outcome, which is sort of pointless... right?

Comment: If [this new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259278/what-should-clicking-on-the-site-logo-questions-links-in-the-site-header-do/259279#259279) is not what you mean, please let me know what I can do differently.

Comment: *"a few ideas on how to make this work better"* - Sorry, but frankly this sounds like it's gonna become even more convoluted and confusing in the future, when the obvious solution is so easy and proved by years of SE user experience. The primary misconception the current implementation is caused by seems to be the assumption that the logo should behave in the exact same way as the "Questions" link, an assumption that doesn't seem too reasonable and can only lead to making this single link overly complex to use. "Questions" works fine, it's just not what I click when I want to see the default.