# "Need Answers" tab has a "Need Answers" filter... Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Not sure if this has been asked before, but:

> [image: Example]

I get that bountied questions, questions with no answer and questions with no accepted answer should appear here, but why is there an *all* option? The all option is basically a clone of the *new* tab's default view. It seems a bit redundant.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are totally right on the redundancy. The new navigation UI is confusing at best.

I find it very hard to understand what action has which end result. Clicking on *need answers* after you hit *bounties* once will show questions with bounties only.

The *all* and *bounties* seem to be redundant to me. I hope they find a better way to show this to us and clear up the UI.

Comment: *"Clicking on need answers after you hit bounties once will show questions with bounties only."* - Another relic of the too eagerly implemented UI persistency request, along with the [completely unintuitive behaviour when clicking the site logo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259278/162011).

Comment: I totally forgot that logo thing. Argh, the new UI is hopeless.