# How to get rid of "recommended" as the default view?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

When I load Stack Overflow (have not tried others) for the first time or switch from another site I see a **recommended** list (filter):

[image: recommended]

I've always preferred the one you get by clicking on `Questions`:

[image: all_tags]

Does the **new layout** make it possible to have this choice (filter) stick?

Answer (score 3):

There is no more recommended filter. And in the redesigned filters submenu on the home page and questions page, your last filter selection is now remembered between page loads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is currently possible based on this interaction between Lance Roberts and Sklivvz

> I notice that now on Meta SO I have the new navigation, and it is defaulting to 'all' in the 'new' tab, while SO is defaulting still to 'recommended'. Is this by design? [Lance Roberts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing/257013#comment838088_256868)

-

> Yeah @LanceRoberts [Sklivvz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing/257013#comment838133_256868)

Until this is implemented use this quick-and-dirty User Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         recommend
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  filter on tags
// @author       rene
// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
$('#hlogo a').attr('href', '/?tagFilter=all');
}());
```

Tested on Chrome with Tampermonkey.

Comment: Do you mean [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256929/the-view-settings-arent-remembered?rq=1)?

Comment: No, that was not the one I had in mind. I did found [this comment and response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing/257013#comment838088_256868) that basically says this is by design on SO at least.